# JavaScript: Floating button to next page

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firebug

there is a site, not mine.
I need a floating button, in the left side or whatever.

There are 3 questions:

1. How to make floating button in my browser?
2. And make this button load next page.
   exmpl: the url is localhost/dev/profile.php?uid=1. after click that button, the page will load localhost/dev/profile.php?uid=2 and subsequently. i wonder how to make uid value increase.

I use mozilla firefox and i noob.

Thanks.
XD

Comment: Can you elaborate, what exactly you mean with "floating button"? And please, show the code you've tried. You have tried something, haven't you?

Comment: no i dont, i am new in js.

Comment: Hmm... "Floating button" is not a specific common term, at least you could explain that? Just show some HTML where this "floating button" occurs or something...

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-w8WHABwTwwM/TdwSUb4cAkI/AAAAAAAAFLY/-z1ECYdrULs/s1600/screenshot%2B1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a floating button you can try : http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html.

For `uid` increase:

- get the current URL with `document.URL`
- parse parameters (after "?")
- get the number with `parseInt`
- increase it
- than assign that parameter to link and access it.